# grep a specific line, print upper lines to a specific word and/or below lines to a specific word

Tags: bash, design-patterns, awk, sed, grep

I'm recently running into an issue where I seem not to find a consistent solution.

Let's say we have some xml file and it's built like the following:

```
...
<tenant>
  <name>bla</name>
  <id>1</id>
  <something>whatever</something>
</tenant>
<tenant>
  <name>foo</name>
  <id>55</id>
  <something>whatever</something>
</tenant>
<tenant>
  <name>waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaey</name>
  <id>8013</id>
  <something>what</something>
</tenant>
...
```

And let's say there might even be more options like `<e-mail>` and some other stuff. So it really can vary of the length there.
Now we know the "something" that it is "whatever" and grep for it. But we don't only want that result, we want all results between `<tenant>` and `</tenant>` that include `<something>whatever</something>`.
Since the number of lines might vary between `<tenant>` and `</tenant>`, I can not use -A, -B or -C on grep.
Any help would be apprechiated here.
I currently just make -C big enough so I have at least all infos between there but maybe once the length will be longer and my method is screwed up.

Comment: post your expected output..

Comment: No longer necessary, Ed Morton's solution works fine and shows my expected output.

Comment: what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: Nothing's wrong. Ed Morton was faster and his solution works so I didn't test yours. Also it seems more complicated for me since I asked for grep/sed/awk and not a new tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='</tenant>' '/<something>whatever<\/something>/{print $0 RT}' file
<tenant>
  <name>bla</name>
  <id>1</id>
  <something>whatever</something>
</tenant>

<tenant>
  <name>foo</name>
  <id>55</id>
  <something>whatever</something>
</tenant>
```

Comment: I forgot to post that I'm using `curl` to receive the xml output. But pyping still works with your solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

awk/grep/sed (regex) is not the right tool for your requirement. because my understanding of your question is:

- valid xml file
- text format could be different, elements could vary, it may be broken into lines, it can contain empty lines.

so, `xpath` is the right way to go:

```
 //tenant[something='whatever']
```

change the `something` and `whatever` you will get the corresponding `tenant` elements.

If you prefer linux cmd tool to do that, `xmllint` is one example:

```
 xmllint --xpath "//tenant[something='whatever']" your.xml
```

Comment: Doesn't pyping work for `xmllint --xpath`? It prints me the usage of xmllint.

Comment: @CommanderCH you need the xml file as input. or `-` let xmllint read from stdin. like : `xxxcmd|xmllint --xpath "..." -` note the last `-`. all those stuffs are written in man page.

Answer (score 0):

The below pcregrep will get the contents between tenant tag only if it's contain the string `<something>whatever</something>`

```
$ pcregrep -M -o '(?s)<tenant>\n\K.*?<something>whatever<\/something>.*?(?=\n<\/tenant>)' file
  <name>bla</name>
  <id>1</id>
  <something>whatever</something>
  <name>foo</name>
  <id>55</id>
  <something>whatever</something>
```

With `<tenant>` tag.

```
$ pcregrep -M -o '(?s)<tenant>\n.*?<something>whatever<\/something>.*?<\/tenant>' file
<tenant>
  <name>bla</name>
  <id>1</id>
  <something>whatever</something>
</tenant>
<tenant>
  <name>foo</name>
  <id>55</id>
  <something>whatever</something>
</tenant>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/<tenant>/{:a;N;\|</tenant>|!ba;\|<something>whatever</something>|p}' file
```